# Fade in background with jQuery on hover then fade out

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently using this code to change my page's css3 background when you hover over a paragraph:

```
$(function(){
    $('#web').hover( function(){
          $('html').css('background', '#000 url("space-image.png") center center fixed no-repeat');
     });
});
```

it works fine but I want to add fadIn to it so it will be smoother.
Also, I would like to fade the new background back to the old one when you are not hovering over the paragraph (#web).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this by using jQuery and jQuery UI and animate the classes instead of having to animate the individual attributes using [SwitchClass](http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/).

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f1_container").hover(function(){
        $("body").switchClass('load', 'webbg', 100);
    },
    function(){
        $("body").switchClass('webbg', 'load', 100);
    });
});
```

Just set the style properties for oldClass and newClass in your CSS. (Renaming appropriately)

Make sure that you are loading the jQuery UI library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yPBVs/**

Comment: seems like the perfect solution in your online demo but is not working on my page. I'm really confused...

Comment: I don't think so... this is what I load: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: That will just be for the core jQuery framework.  Modify your HTML to include the <script> tags in my updated solution.

Comment: I have the jQuery UI library loaded (and still have the framework loaded) and still no luck! Please help

Comment: Is your page live or in a dev environment?  If its not live, then can you post the full HTML code of your page? O

Comment: Yes, if possible. I'm thinking there is something else going on here.

Comment: I just made a fiddle. It looks different and doesn't have the images, but see http://jsfiddle.net/fl_pirate/N3h9W/

Comment: It looks like the issue was the way you were trying to access the listeners. You need to encase them in $(document).ready(function(){  //INSERT YOUR FUNCTIONS HERE  });

Comment: I don't really get what you're saying (sorry, I'm new to jQuery)EDIT: I get it

Comment: Simply change the duration of the effect, which you currently have set to '100' in your code.  The higher the number, then the longer the transition will be.  And if that did in fact help then I would appreciate having the solution accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jQuery` `animate()` to animate css changes over time.

**[EDIT]**

Your code should use something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('#web').hover( function() {
        $('html').animate({
            background: #000 url("space-image.png") center center fixed no-repeat
        }, 5000, 
        function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

Example code from [api.jquery.com/animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried that code just now and it won't change the background...do I need to load another jQuery file

Comment: You should just need `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` with whatever version of jQuery you're using.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#web').hover( 
    function() { $("#myOverlay").fadeIn(); }, 
    function() { $("#myOverlay").fadeOut(); }
});
```

I don't think you can fade the background, there is nothing under it. You would need an overlay.

Comment: Hey, fiddle is COOL! Here is what I am talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/yPBVs/18/

Comment: @robB can I know why the downvote? (guessing , siaiw) I can guess my style is not super, even kinda vague, like, what do I mean by an 'overlay', and I avoided using jQuery UI, but then again, neither of the answers above actually work, they do not fade the image in the background. If you make an absolute positioned div with the alternate image in it, and fade that in and out with whatever method you want, that works, and delivers what OP was asking for. Ciao, bb

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#f1_container").hover(function(){
$("body").switchClass('load', 'webbg', 950);
},
function(){
$("body").switchClass('webbg', 'load', 950);
});
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#f1_container2").hover(function(){
$("body").switchClass('load', 'photobg', 950);
},
function(){
$("body").switchClass('photobg', 'load', 950);
});
});
</script>
```

That is the solution I'll use. Thanks for the help.